# How to read a class file from an extracted jar file?

Tags: java, class, file-io, jar

I want to read a **`.class`** file that is located inside of a **`.jar`** package. How can I read a readable `.class` file from a `.jar` package?

My environment is:

- Language version: `Java`
- Platform version: `Java 1.8.0_73`
- Runtime: `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)`
- VM Server: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)`
- Operating system: `Windows 10 Home (64-bit) [build 10586]`

---

**EDIT:**

My extracted `.class` file that contains binary & compiled bytecode:

[image: The .class file contains binary & compiled bytecode]

The output I want:

[image: The .java file - readable code]

Comment: Post your code, tell us what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: Do you want to read the `.class` file to execute it or to display it? Or what is your intention?

Comment: @JBNizet he doesn't want to make a program, he just want to read a .class file.

Comment: @RoccoT-RoccoDeveloping That's your interpretation of the unclear question. The 3 posted links all ask how to programmatically, in Java, read a file from a jar. So i tend to think this interpretation is not the right one.

Comment: I extracted a `.jar` file but I can't read the `.class` files with Notepad++. I only want to display and study the code.

Comment: .class files contain binary, compiled bytecode. Not source code. .java files contain the source code.

Comment: I used 7-zip and dg-gui.

Comment: But, please go to tutorials instead of decompiling. Nothing is impossible.

Comment: Follow my new comment under my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a [decompiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler). I prefer using [Fernflower](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower), or if you use IntelliJ IDEA, simply open .class files from there, because it has Fernflower pre-installed.

Or, go to [javadecompilers.com](http://javadecompilers.com), upload your .jar file, use CFR and download the decompiled .zip file.

However, in some cases, decompiling code is quite illegal, so, prefer to learn instead of decompiling.

Comment: And in other cases, code is also obfuscated, so you can't see method names, because they're like a(), aB() etc.

Comment: I got files like `a.class` ... `l.class`. What should I do?

Comment: Use a decompiler and open them

Comment: Or, go to http://www.javadecompilers.com, upload your .jar file, use CFR and download the decompiled .zip file.

Comment: Mark the question as answered by ticking my answer and, if you want, gimme a +1. It would be very appreciated. Glad it worked!

Comment: Done it. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 5):

#### Extract the Contents of `.zip`/`.jar` files programmatically

Suppose `.jar` file is the `.jar`/`.zip` file to be extracted. `destDir` is the path where it will be extracted:

```
java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new java.util.jar.JarFile(jarFile);
java.util.Enumeration enum = jar.entries();
while (enum.hasMoreElements()) {
    java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) enum.nextElement();
    java.io.File f = new java.io.File(destDir + java.io.File.separator + file.getName());
    if (file.isDirectory()) { // if its a directory, create it
        f.mkdir();
        continue;
    }
    java.io.InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(file); // get the input stream
    java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);
    while (is.available() > 0) {  // write contents of 'is' to 'fos'
        fos.write(is.read());
    }
    fos.close();
    is.close();
}
```